Collaboration diagram for Swift Care Ambulance using IoT powered system
Want a collaboration diagram for Swift Care Ambulance
It should provide a message alert when accident detected by gyro accelerometer sensor
It should note the patient heart rate using heart beat sensor
It should not the temperature and humidity using temperature sensor
Want a collaboration diagram for Swift Care Ambulance

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
